# Kendo Grid: How to sort (and filter) a column bound to a simple json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have seen a number of questions on sorting, but I couldn't find any for my very simple case.

I have taken the online [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/@SiliconSoul/oJIqI) (where if I add the sortable and filterable, they don't work on the category field either), and modified it very slightly, just to use very simple local json data (to make it eaier to see what I am working with while learning the grid.

So, looking at the category field I want to sort and filter, in my columns definition I have  ....

```
 columns: [
  {
    ...
  {
    field: "Category",
    title: "Category",
    width: "180px",        
    editor: categoryDropDownEditor,
    template: "#=Category.description#"
  },
```

and in the data source, the category field consists on s simple json object with 2 fields code and description (where code it to be the value field, and description is what to display) ...

```
var gridData = [
{
....
ProductID : 1,
ProductName : "Chai",
Category : {
    code : '1',
    description : "Beverages",

 },
...
];
```

I have added the sortable, and filterable properties to the grid however the category field show the sort arrows (which toggle when clicked), but the column data does not sort or filter.

How do I will the sort and filter to look at the description field to carry out these operations?

Note I also have a combo cell editor attached

```
function createCombo(container, options, data) {
  var input = $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
  input.appendTo(container)
  var combobox = input.kendoComboBox({
    autoBind: true,
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "select...",
    suggest: true,
    dataTextField: "description",
    dataValueField: "code",
    dataSource: data,
  });
```

where the data is of form

```
[ 
  {code: 'code1', description: 'desc1'},
  {code: 'code2', description: 'desc2'},
]
```

So I would need the combo to also populate the field with the correct value.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your link doesn't contain your example. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <script>

    var gridData = [
{
    ProductID: 1,
    ProductName: "Chai",
    Category: {
        code: '1',
        description: "beverages",

    }
},
 {
     ProductID: 1,
     ProductName: "bhai",
     Category: {
         code: '1',
         description: "aceverages",

     }
 },
  {
      ProductID: 1,
      ProductName: "dhai",
      Category: {
          code: '1',
          description: "zeverages",

      }
  }
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: gridData,
            height: 550,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "ProductID",
                title: "Contact Name",
                width: 200
            }, {
                field: "ProductName",
                title: "Contact Title"
            }, {
                field: "Category.description",
                title: "Category",
                width: "180px",
                template: "#=Category.description#"
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you  ashutosh jambhale. I jusr added info on the attached combobox, so now the the field name has the .description in it, the combo seem to now post the code . I tried `input.on('change', function () {
        var val = input.val();    
        //var dataItem = input.dataItem();
        options.model.set(options.field, val + 'xx');
      });` but it didn't work (val() is the code). Ideas on this last piece to the puzzle? Cheers

Comment: Actually I suppose the above (wit the combo)  is a different question so I thought I'd add in in a new post (where I can also format it properly).. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405048/kendo-grid-how-to-get-the-selected-item-from-a-combobox-cell-template-when-usin