# Kendo Grid: how to get the selected item from a Combobox cell template when using with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which I am using within Angular, and have a field with a combo box, that has the editor set to the following function...

```
 function comboCellTemplate(container, options) {
  var input = $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
  input.appendTo(container)
  var combobox = input.kendoComboBox({
    autoBind: true,
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "select...",
    suggest: true,
    dataTextField: "description",
    dataValueField: "code",
    dataSource: data,
  });
```

And data is a list of simple json objects...

```
[
  {code: 'code1', description: 'desc1'}
  {code: 'code2', description: 'desc2'}
[
```

Each field in the grid data is bound to the same objects (ie with a code and description field)

I a previous post, to get sorting and filtering working I need to bind a field to the display field...

```
 {
      field: "Category.description",
      title: "Category",
      editor: comboCellTemplate,
      template: "#=Category.description#"
  },
```

When I do this, the combo box seems to set the field of the grid to the code.
How can I get this to set the grid data to the whole data object (ie the {code, description})

I have tried adding a on - change handler to do this

```
  input.on('change', function () {
    var val = input.val();              
            //var dataItem = input.dataItem();
    options.model.set(options.field, val + 'xx');
  });
```

but can't see how to get the "selected Item" from the combo

I don't seem to be able to find this in the help (in particular when using Angular)

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.
regards, Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply add a change handler to the editor and set it from there:

```
function comboCellTemplate(container, options) {
    var input = $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
    input.appendTo(container)
    var combobox = input.kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: true,
        filter: "contains",
        placeholder: "select...",
        suggest: true,
        dataTextField: "description",
        dataValueField: "code",
        dataSource: data,
        change: function () {
            options.model.set(options.field, this.dataItem());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Lars. I tried this out, and the dataItem() does return the selected item.  However if the field is set to "Category" the above will just do what the combo does automatically. If I set the field to "Category.description", then the above sets the description field to an object, so that is no good. If you use **options.model.set(options.field, this.dataItem().description);** (with the field set to Category.description), then at first this appears to have everything working (ie the display look right, and the filter and sort work). Prob is the model code is not updated :-(

Comment: OK, I see; difficult to do this without trying - so if you know which column you're going to use this for, try `options.model.set("Category", this.dataItem());` (you could also make it generic by passing the actual field through a closure, or you could  `options.field.split(".") ` and use the first part)

Comment: Hi Lars, yes sorry I went off on another path, but came back to this. Yes using the above, I can now do exactly what I want (I get the base field name, and then set the code and description fields individually.

Comment: Just had one remaining issue that I have just discovered with the above. Posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535116/kendo-grid-setting-model-fields-on-combox-selection-breaks-the-combobox-up-down. If I can get around this, it will be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have got to the bottom of this (after lots of diving through the doco)

I could get everything to work after I discovered that you can give a column a "magical" compare function.

So using this, my field can go back to binding to the whole json object ..
and add the sortable as follows...

```
{
  field: "Category",
  title: "Category",
  editor: comboCellTemplate,
  template: "#=Category.description#",
  sortable:{
        compare: function (a, b){
          return a.Category.description.localeCompare(b.Category.description);
        }
```

},

Now everything works exactly as I expect, and I don't need to do anything extra in the combobox. I hope this ("simple when you know how") tip can save someone else all the time it took me to find it.

Comment: Dammit, the same thing doesn't work for the filtering! I am devastated.