# Kendo Grid: Setting Model fields on combox selection breaks the combobox up/down arrow scrolling

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

this follows in from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405048/kendo-grid-how-to-get-the-selected-item-from-a-combobox-cell-template-when-usin) to do with setting a grid's selected fields when we have a data source field (and combo fields) with a json object (as opposed to a simple string).

So if we look at the change event handler for the following combox...

```
function createCombo(container, options, data) {
  var input = $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
  input.appendTo(container)
  input.kendoComboBox({
  autoBind: true,
  filter: "contains",
  placeholder: "select...",
  suggest: true,
  dataTextField: "display",
  dataValueField: "rego",
  dataSource: data,
  change: function () {                     
    var dataItem = this.dataItem();
    var dataField = options.field.split('.');

     var fieldName = dataField[0];          
     options.model.set(fieldName + '.rego', dataItem.rego);
     options.model.set(fieldName + '.display', dataItem.display);      
    }
 });
 }
```

I am setting my 2 fields as follows...

```
    options.model.set(fieldName + '.rego', dataItem.rego);
    options.model.set(fieldName + '.display', dataItem.display);
```

(each item in the combo, and the grid data source has a json object with a 'rego' and 'display' field, see full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/r28vmg6f/9/).

This seemed to work exactly as I wanted, but I had just had someone point out to me that when you scroll the combobox with the up/down arrow keys, it just seems to toggle between 2 values in the list, as opposed to iterating through all the items.  If I remove the 2 'options.model.set' statements, the combo then behaves.

I am really hoping there is a work around this, but everything I Have tried makes no different.

If there were any suggestion to finish this off, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're modifying the model manually, you should to remove the `name=...` attribute from the input (otherwise the grid will also modify the model; you could also use `name="car.rego"` - it has to be the value field - and then not set the combobox value in the config) and also only call `set` for the last change you make on the model (otherwise, the grid's save event will get triggered twice, once with invalid data).

So you editor would look like this:

```
function createCombo(container, options, data) {
    var dataField = options.field.split('.');
    var fieldName = dataField[0];

    var input = $('<input/>')
    input.appendTo(container)
    input.kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: true,
        filter: "contains",
        placeholder: "select...",
        suggest: true,
        dataTextField: "display",
        dataValueField: "rego",
        dataSource: data,
        value: options.model[fieldName].rego,
        change: function (e) {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem();
            options.model[fieldName]['rego'] = dataItem.rego;
            options.model.set(fieldName + '.display', dataItem.display);
        }
    });
}
```

Also, your data should be consistent (in one DS, you use "C1" as rego, in the other "CAR1").

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txtpxgoL/))

Comment: Thank you very much Lars, and yes I did get the sample car rego mismatched (in a real app they would always be the same as will be from the same database). At any rate, the combo seems to work perfectly! I will re-read some of the doco in the <input> etc to try and fully understand what the above syntax does mean. Cheers again.